# Writing data in NetCDF file from multiple processors

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, netcdf

I have a simulation on meteorological field, my total domain (nx * ny * nz) is divided into number of processors (in my case 100). I have to send the job file created by local machine to the cluster for execution.

I want to write the Fortran routine for writing the output data from each processor into a NetCDF file.

Following is my code snippet, in `user_init.f90`

```
stat = NF90_CREATE('/home/sachin/e_output.nc', NF90_NETCDF4, ncid_user, comm = comm2d,info = MPI_INFO_NULL)

stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, i, NF90_UNLIMITED, i_id )
stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, j, NF90_UNLIMITED, j_id )
stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, k, NF90_UNLIMITED, k_id )

e_id=i_id(/i_id,j_id,k_id/)

stat = NF90_DEF_VAR( ncid_user, ene, NF90_INT, e_id, ev_id )
```

From other file I am writing the output data into the NetCDF file

```
stat1 = nf90_put_var(ncid_user, ev_id, pt, start = (/ 1 + myid*INT(procs1), 1 + myid*INT(procs1), 1 /),count = (/ 152,120,120 /))
```

Comment: How id it divided? Which part of the field is in which processor? Is it MPI? Please supply more details.

Comment: Sir, id is divided depending on number of given processors for this program total field is 120*120*152 and number of processors are given as 100, So the field is distributed among 10 (sqrt(100)) processors on x and y axis each. so for processor of rank 0 will gets the field 12*12*152 and so on... The communication is done through MPI.

Comment: So you must show how you setup the MPI topology in NetCDF.

Comment: Sir, MPI topology is created automatically when I run the simulation process. It is written in other fortran routines which executed at initial of this model. So I have to write only  netcdf routines in one of the fortran file.

Comment: Yes, but you must tell netcdf how this topology looks like. Study this https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2009/pnetcdf/index.html and come back after you have finished it.